# Running WCF Service Host on a different port

Tags: wcf, port80

Is it possible to run `WcfSvcHost.exe` (WCF Service Host) that ships with Visual Studio to run on a port other than port 80? I am trying to debug a WCF service, but my machine is already running Apache on port 80.

I could go and set Apache to use a different port, but it would be easier if there is a way to do it in `WcfSvcHost`.

Currently when I try to run my service project, it gives me the dreaded "port in use" message:

> > 'HTTP could not register URL http://+:80/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/a655b03e-30ff-4818-b561-ef52e4cb1e3d/ because TCP port 80 is being used by another application.'

Comment: I did not use WCFSvcHost to host the service, since IIS express will automatically starts when debugging the service. In my opinion, we could use IIS express as the default debugging tool which host the service, and it is convenient to change by using open the property of the WCF project.

Comment: I wonder how do you start the WCFSvchost to host the service when debugging. I didn't find the option on my side when debugging my WCF service application. it seems the default debugging tool is IIS Express and the wcfsvchost is  removed in VS2019

Comment: @AbrahamQian: Not so on my end. I used **Windows service** template and then added a WCF service into it. Now when I run the project, it is automatically hosted in `WCFSvcHost`. This could have something to do with the fact that I do not have IIS Express installed on my machine, which in turn could be because I did not install web development components at installation time.

Comment: Do know that wcfsvchost does have an .config file in the IDE folder of VS and you should be able to add a service specif config there. In theory that should resolve the port conflict (assuming you chose something sane there) but I'm not sure if the debug experience somehow relies on that global discovery address. IOW maybe it is not your service that throws here but the debug tooling.

Comment: @rene: That is correct. It is `WCFSvcHost.exe` that is trying to use port 80. The WCF service itself uses port `6732` and this can be configured easily from `app.config` file of the service project.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the solution with us? ^.^

Comment: @AbrahamQian: Currently I have simply changed my web server (Apache) to use a different port. `WcfSvcHost` is now happily running at port 80. :-)